# Authenticate on SignalR console application from JS client

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

Following scenario/my solution consists of the following:

Project one: (`SELF HOST`) I have a `SignalR` console application which handles the logic including the authentication process ( queries database with `EF` ).
 Project two: (`CLIENT`) I have an `ASP.Net web application` with an `AngularJS` client.

So far I can talk to the hub just fine. The problem is, I cannot seem to get the authentication to work. I've tried a bunch of things I've found but none of them worked. Most of them didn't even apply to my problem..

Currently I've stripped my project back to the basics and I have the following code:

Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

My hub:

```
[HubName("systemHub")]
public class systemHub : Hub
{

    public void Authenticate(String pLogin, String pPassword)
    {
        User curUser = new AuthManager().Authenticate(pLogin, pPassword);
//this is where I'd want to send the auth cookie or whatever and contact the "loginCallback" function in my client
    }

    [Authorize]
    public void Hello(String pMessage)
    {
        Clients.All.callbackFunc(pMessage);
    }
}
```

Js client:

```
    hinagApp.controller('hinagController', function ($scope) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var conURL = 'http://localhost:8080/signalr';
        $.getScript(conURL + '/hubs', function () {
            $.connection.hub.url = conURL;
            var lHub = $.connection.systemHub;

            lHub.client.callbackFunc = function(pM){
                alert(pM);
            }

            lHub.client.loginCallback = function (pSuccess) {
                if (pSuccess) {
                    //if logged in
                    lHub.server.hello("test");
                }
                else {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            }

            $('#loginbutton').click(function () {
                lHub.server.authenticate($('#input_login').val(), $('#input_pass').val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: have you checked out http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization ?

Comment: Yes. There's no example for a js client.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: None, so far. That's the problem. Ideally I want to authenticate through my hub, somehow. ( Please look at `Authenticate()` ) I've been using FormsAuthentication on other projects but all of them were ASP.Net projects with SignalR. This time the SignalR part is self-hosted. I've googled but I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried simply to do FormsAuthentification? SignalR should work fine with authentication cookies. So here, in public void Authenticate(String pLogin, String pPassword) do FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

Comment: There is no asp.net environment in the signalr project, therefore it's stateless and I cannot store the cookie as far as I understand. Either way, I've tried it before as I've been doing that on other projects, like I said, but it doesn't work.

Tried it just now: 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: Can you put exact example somewhere? (github, bitbucket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar problem. If I understand you right, you want to do the authentication on your signalr server application. Signalr can accept standard webrequests just fine.

Set the authenticationtype to cookies:

```
        CookieAuthenticationOptions lOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Auth/Logout"),
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(lOptions);
```

If user wants to login, set the claims you'd like to use

```
var lForm = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lForm["input_login"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lForm["input_pass"]))
                    {
                        //Benutzer authentifizieren
                        var lAuthenticatedUser = new UserManager().Authenticate(lForm["input_login"], lForm["input_pass"]);
                        if (lAuthenticatedUser != null)
                        {
                            //Existiert der Nutzer legen wir die Claims an
                            ClaimsIdentity lIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(lOptions.AuthenticationType);
                            lIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, lAuthenticatedUser.Username));
                            lIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, lAuthenticatedUser.InternalUserId.ToString()));
                            lIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, context.Request.RemoteIpAddress));

                            //Und zum Schluss einloggen
                            context.Authentication.SignIn(lIdentity);

                            //Und auf die Spieleseite weiterleiten
                            context.Response.Redirect(BLL._Configuration.HinagGameURL);
                        }
                    }
```

If you want to serve the login page you can do it like this (_Authpage is your page as String, for example)

```
                else if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/Auth/")
            {
                if (context.Authentication.User != null)
                    context.Response.Redirect(BLL._Configuration.HinagGameURL);


                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(_Authpage);
            }
```

If the user needs anything else ( such as additional style files in your authpage )

```
                else
            {
                await next();
            }
```

All of this belongs in your Startup.

Comment: I didn't realize I could serve webpages just like that. Does SignalR recognize what to do just by browsing an URL? Do I need to register those anywhere else? If not, this seems pretty solid.

Comment: Yes, you can. You don't need to register them anywhere else. At least I don't know where and if you can do that. I haven't really looked into that as I only need to serve the auth page.

Answer (score 0):

In `Startup.cs` you need to add forms authentication middleware (probably you need to tune it a bit):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
});
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I don't see how this may work in a console environment.

Answer (score -1):

You kind screwed up Angular with that code. Try this one:

```
hinagApp
    .controller('hinagController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var conURL = 'http://localhost:8080/signalr';
    var lHub = $.connection.systemHub;

    lHub.client.callbackFunc = function(pM){
        alert(pM);
    }

    lHub.client.loginCallback = function (pSuccess) {
        if (pSuccess) {
            //if logged in
            lHub.server.hello("test");
        }
        else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    }

    $http
        .get(conURL + '/hubs')
        .then(function(response) {
            $.connection.hub.url = conURL;
            $('#loginbutton').click(function () {
                lHub.server.authenticate($('#input_login').val(), $('#input_pass').val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
});
```

Comment: Huh? The connection is working just fine. I just don't know how to authenticate.

Comment: Thats out of my scope.